# How to render html description (from API response) into simple text in Android EditText input field?

Tags: android, rest, api, android-edittext

I have an EditText field in my app which I convert to HTML and send it to the backend to store it in HTML form so that we render it according to input HTML wherever needed.

Now, When I want to edit the same information, I am getting the response in HTML from API but EditText is not converting back to normal text (with usual HTML to normal text rendering preserving the formatting done by HTML).

I tried different methods related to EditText but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know the solution around it?

Comment: below I have given answer maybe it help you.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to use Html.fromHtml() to use HTML in your XML Strings. Simply referencing a String with HTML in your layout XML will not work.*

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
    } else { 
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
    }
```

Comment: Example API Response- 
<p> This is a <h1> paragraph </h1> </br> This is new line </br> another new line </p>

In my EditText input box I want this-
`This is a paragraph`
`This is new line`
`another new line`

is your snippet supposed to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer please try the new updated answer.I sure this will solve your problem.